# deleted URI but image still shows in react native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

Im using react native in vs code and i had a link to a uri and i have remove this from my code entirely. When i refreshed my code the image remained and will not disappear from my screen (android emulator). It was originally in the imageBackground tag. I have tried clearing cache and looked in all my folders for any other link but it doesnt exist anywhere. Ive also rebuilt package, restarted machine etc

Any idea on how to remove this image as i can only presume its being cached somewhere?

Comment: How are you showing image in view? Share some piece of code what are you doing then could help you in that.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me on this as its now randomly disappeared. Im not sure what happened but it seems to have resolved itself. I believe it was some sort of cache issue